Get Records between dates and exist at least 3 times
I have table with over 35 million email records.
I need to get all of the records between a date range and also exist at least 3 times in the table.
1 email may have more than one property but will never have the same property twice.
The table looks like this:



EMAIL
PROPERTY
LAST_SENT_DATE




email1
prop1
2024-06-25


email2
prop1
2024-06-16


email3
prop2
2024-06-02


email4
prop3
2024-06-25


email1
prop2
2024-06-26


email1
prop3
2024-06-10



So I want to write a query that will return the emails in June but exist more than 3 times.
SELECT * FROM `myTable` 
WHERE 
(
  (`last_sent_date` BETWEEN '2024-06-01' AND '2024-06-30') 
   AND 
  (//...SOME PROPERTY COUNT HERE)
) 

The results should look like this:



EMAIL
PROPERTY
LAST_SENT_DATE




email1
prop1
2024-06-25


email1
prop2
2024-06-26


email1
prop3
2024-06-10



I'm guessing it needs to do some kind of COUNT on PROPERTY, but I'm not sure where or how to add it.

@Akina, those Markdown tables are too high for my small laptop screen...

SELECT Email FROM MyTable where last_sent_date between '2024-06-01' AND '2024-06-30' group by email having count(email)=3

Do the property values matter? Does exist at least 3 times with same property count?

@jarlh - I guess the property doesn't matter since no email will have more than 1 property but the email itself may exist multiple times.

The question is slightly ambiguous. It's not clear yet whether all three rows must exist in the range, or whether it's enough that three records exists anywhere, as long as at least one is in the date range.

Well, it's pretty much straightforward, you can use an EXIST clause. this is the more efficient way because it allows the database to stop searching as soon it finds a matching row:
Here is the code:
SELECT mt.*
FROM `myTable` mt
WHERE mt.`last_sent_date` BETWEEN '2024-06-01' AND '2024-06-30'
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM `myTable` mt2
  WHERE mt2.`email` = mt.`email`
  GROUP BY mt2.`email`
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT mt2.`property`) > 3
)

This query uses an EXIST clause to check if there is at least one row in the subquery is matches the email column.
Just advice: consider creating an index on the email and last_sent_date columns to improve the performance.

I am getting an error that is pointing to "near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 6" even though that text does not exist in the query.

@JohnBeasley your client is adding that.  Consider using the command line client, which doesn't lie to you

Looks like I was missing a parenthesis.  The query is running now, but it's taking a while.  I may have to create that index as indicated.

Index is needed and that will improve the efficiency and will return the result faster.

This will work, but I expect we can do better with a window function

WITH
cte AS (
  SELECT email, property, last_sent_date,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY email) cnt
  FROM test
  WHERE last_sent_date BETWEEN '2024-06-01' AND '2024-06-30'
)
SELECT email, property, last_sent_date
FROM cte
WHERE cnt >= 3;




email
property
last_sent_date




email1
prop1
2024-06-25


email1
prop2
2024-06-26


email1
prop3
2024-06-10



fiddle

at least 3 times in the table in the table, not in the date range.  not totally clear, but that's my reading  (I didn't downvote, that was someone else)

@ysth that's also how I read the text, but the example data/results lend themselves to the alternative (3 rows must be in the range). The don't definitely show this, but they lend themselves to that interpretation, and I tend to trust the examples more.

That said: if I were writing the query, the PARTITION BY would also check the last_sent_date, to ensure the months match. I know the WHERE already cover this, but I like to be thorough.

@ysth If so then the condition by last_sent_date must be moved to outer query.

Find below some of the options to get your expected result with the data provided:
--      S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table tbl ( EMAIL Text,  PROPERTY Text,  LAST_SENT_DATE Date );
Insert Into tbl
  Select 'email1',  'prop1',    '2024-06-25' Union All 
  Select 'email2',  'prop1',    '2024-06-16' Union All 
  Select 'email3',  'prop2',    '2024-06-02' Union All 
  Select 'email4',  'prop3',    '2024-06-25' Union All 
  Select 'email1',  'prop2',    '2024-06-26' Union All 
  Select 'email1',  'prop3',    '2024-06-10';

1. Inner Join with filtered data
SELECT   t.*
FROM   ( Select   EMAIL
         From     tbl
         Where    LAST_SENT_DATE Between '2024-06-01' And '2024-06-30'
         Group By EMAIL
         Having   Count(EMAIL) >= 3 ) e
INNER JOIN tbl t ON(t.EMAIL = e.EMAIL)

2. Filtered using Where Clause's IN() condition
SELECT   t.*
FROM     tbl t
WHERE    t.EMAIL IN( Select   EMAIL
                     From     tbl
                     Where    LAST_SENT_DATE Between '2024-06-01' And '2024-06-30'
                     Group By EMAIL
                     Having   Count(EMAIL) >= 3 
                   ) 

3. Filtered with EXISTS(corelated subquery)
SELECT   t.*
FROM     tbl t
WHERE    LAST_SENT_DATE Between '2024-06-01' And '2024-06-30' And
         EXISTS ( Select   1
                  From     tbl
                  Where    EMAIL = t.EMAIL
                  Group By EMAIL
                  Having   Count(EMAIL) >= 3 
               ) 

... all of the above sql statements have the same outcome:
/*    R e s u l t :
EMAIL   PROPERTY    LAST_SENT_DATE
------  ----------  --------------
email1  prop1       2024-06-25
email1  prop2       2024-06-26
email1  prop3       2024-06-10      */

See the fiddle here.
NOTE:
With real data the results will not be the same depending on an open question about number of rows with the same EMAIL should be only within the date range or it can be counted together with rows before the range / after the range / before and after the range. Where condition filtering the date range should be moved accordingly (and/or adjusted) to get what you realy want.
Code no 1. and 2. filter the rows counting EMAIL appearances just within the date range. Code no. 3 does the counting over all the data.
